# Custom Address field is not writable. Error in apex

Tags: apex, address

I have enabled Custom Address field in my org. My requirement is I want to assign Account's Billing address field value to Case's Custom address field but when try to compile the code, I get an error message:

"Field is not writeable:"

Can someone please help? Is Custom Address field is not supported in apex?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide the actual code that causes this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update address field directly. Instead you need to update individual fields like `City,State,Country code` .. etc.

Suppose the address field name is `sample_address__c` individual fields will be created like `sample_address__City__s,sample_address__CountryCode__s,sample_address__PostalCode__s` ...etc.

You have to update the above fields with `BillingCity,Billingstate` ..etc